# yml pipeline: publish artifact with code from multiple repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, artifact

I am attempting to build code from multiple repositories and publish it as a single build artifact.

When I checkout another repository it clears the ArtifactStagingDirectory.

Is there a way to save code between jobs?

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: Engineering/A
    ref: master
  - repository: B
    type: git
    name: Engineering/B
    ref: pipeline_publish

jobs:
- job: jobA
  steps:
  - checkout: A
  - template: Pipelines/BuildTemplate.yml@A
  - template: Pipelines/CopyPluginsTemplate.yml@A
    parameters:
      destinationFolder: A

- job: jobB
  steps:
  - checkout: B
  - template: Pipelines/BuildTemplate.yml@A
  - template: Pipelines/CopyPluginsTemplate.yml@A
    parameters:
      destinationFolder: B

- job: jobPublishArtifact
  dependsOn:
  - jobA
  - jobB
  steps:
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish Files to be used by the Release build
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'HMI'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: every job it's a new fresh agent. why you can't do it in one job?

Comment: I have to checkout the different repositories so it can't be one job.

Comment: you can checkout multiple repos in one job...

Comment: You are right. Apparently checking out multiple repos in one job changes the path. That was why it was failing when I tried one job earlier.

Comment: So do you prefer a solution of one job or multiple jobs?

Comment: I haven't been able to get the path to work for a single job. I keep getting 'No files matched the search pattern' for the DotNetCoreCLI NuGet restore.

This happens if for both
a) projects:  '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/**/*.csproj'
b) projects:  '**/*.csproj'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple answer, No. However, if you want to "play" with artifacts, you can download the build results of the previous agent run. As example:

Stage 1:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

steps:
- script: 'echo "Write your commands here" >> $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/fl1.txt'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: drop
```

Stage 2:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

steps:
- script: |
   echo "Hello world"  >> $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/fl2.txt
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    artifactName: drop
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: drop1
```

The build results:

[image]